# Delta function on messages returning duplicate key "id" in response

Tags: json, odata, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using Microsoft Graph Delta functionality to track changes in a message folder, I built my request referring to the [Delta documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_messages)

When I received the response, it has duplicate key `id` in it.

Request URL:

```
/v1.0/users/me/mailFolders('inbox')/messages/delta?$top=2&$select=id
```

and this is the response I am receiving:

```
{
  "@odata.context":
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(message)",
  "@odata.nextLink":
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/me/mailFolders('inbox')/messages/delta?$skiptoken={token}",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.message",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"{etag}\"",
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.message",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"{etag}",
      "id": "xxxxxxx",
      "id": "xxxxxxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or missing here? TIA

Comment: Would you please provide request ids to investigate this?

Comment: @PoojaPatel I'm not op but I'm experiencing the same issue. Here is a request id where it happened: cb2057a8-e7d7-40df-aee3-b9961cbdf0ce

Comment: are you still experiencing the issue, could you provide a new request id? (sorry for the miss in follow up)